# Can I get the field structure from a Dapper query?

Tags: c#, dapper

I've been looking through the source code, but there is a fair amount going on for such a small ORM. Is there any way to retrieve the field structure of a query returned by Dapper after calling .Query()? Essentially I need the same data as returned by a DataReader when you call GetSchemaTable().

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as follows:

Fetch the reader using either of the following calls:

```
IDataReader dr = _connection.ExecuteReader(sql)
```

or

```
IDataReader dr = _connection.GetStream(sql)
```

Now you can call `dr.GetSchemaTable()` to get the relevant schema `DataTable` 
In fact you may typecast the same to relevant `DbDataReader` type like `SqlDataReader or OracleDataReader`in case you want to utilize an overload of a `GetSchemaTable()`

Comment: So how do you materialize it into an IEnumerable<dynamic> or a specific type then?

Comment: Not sure if you have a specific requirement to create an IEnumerable<T> via DataReader, since that can be fetched directly using Dapper Query<T>   call. For conversion from DataReader you need to use Reflection, check the following link - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827984/Generically-Populate-List-of-Objects-from-SqlDataR
Point remains, Create an entity, apply attribute to map to the Column names fetched from the Database, then fill each property of an object with each call of DataReader.Read()

Comment: But that's kind of the point of using Dapper - I want it to do the mapping. I just happen to have the additional need of getting at the result metadata. I want to do a .Query() or .Query<> call, but then retrieve the metadata about this result. Yes, I can do all of this manually but I'd rather not if at all possible (hence the question).

Comment: Dapper as a Micro ORM, is fairly useful for lot of common scenarios, which requires fetching Poco, One to one mapping and One to many mapping out of box, which makes it a great micro ORM to use. However, not all perceived use cases are covered out of box. Fetching schema while using a Query<T> syntax is mostly not there, but you may want to either ask the same @ https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues or may plan to modify Dapper code to expose the necessary API